# How/where does Google App Engine cache YAML (changing `script`)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Originally I had this in my `app.yaml`:

```yaml
runtime: python39

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

I changed the script filename to `gae.py` and so updated `app.yaml` to thus:

```yaml
runtime: python39

- url: .*
  script: gae.app
```

The new version no longer starts up:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'

I have tried changing the `url` but it's still trying to use a now-non-existent `main.py` to load the WSGI application. When I view the source of the version I see the correct `app.yaml` and file structure; I don't see `main` mentioned *anywhere*.

Any ideas?

[image: A peek at the Source from the web console]

Comment: I don't know, but why do you want to change this?  I'd just keep it as it was.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not caching but rather that `script` is no longer used (and is ignored) in the Python 3 world of Google App Engine standard:

> **script**: Optional. Specifies that requests to the specific handler should target your app. The only accepted value for the script element is auto because all traffic is served using the entrypoint command. In order to use static handlers, at least one of your handlers must contain the line script: auto or define an entrypoint element to deploy successfully.

(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element)

The fix is to override `entrypoint` which defaults to:

```
/bin/sh -c exec gunicorn main:app --workers 2 -c /config/gunicorn.py
```

(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup)